# Large icons, windows, fonts, etc

Tags: settings, desktop, icons

I have a computer connected to an LCD TV with a Radeon 6770HD

During installation everything was fine, but when I boot everything is very large.

Installing the drivers from the AMD website didn't help.

For some reason, this is not an issue on Ubuntu or Mint - just elementary OS and Trenta.

Comment: Welcome to elementary OS, could you add output of: `sudo lshw -C display` and  `xrandr`

Answer (score 1):

there is a good change you have a scaling factor applied (which is only intended for HiDPI screens normally).

In a terminal type:

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor`

If it outputs anything greater than 1 (mine is `uint32 2` ), then you can try this:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1`

For reference `uint32` is just a description of the "type" of the number, it isn't really interesting to regular users, and it means Unsigned Integer (think positive whole number), stored in 32-Binary Digits (bits).