# Desktop resolution

Tags: resolution

how can I set up my screen, so it wouldn't look so oversized?
i've got 15" screen with 1366x768 resolution, but now all the icons, header bar, wingpanel are looking big. is there a way to set all of it to 75% size? I know Windows10 has got something similar

Answer (score 2):

open terminal and execute:

```
xrandr --query
```

In the output look for the name of your primary monitor, for me:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 170mm
```

so its eDPI!

now again in terminal:

```
xrandr --output eDPI --scale 1.25x1.25
```

put your Device name where eDPI is for me. You can experiment with the scaling factor. 1x1 is normal, 1.5x1.5 is 50% as big.

If you like what you see you can add the command that suits you to Startup-Applications (system-settings->applications->the right tab).

Comment: thanks,it works as you describe, but screen becomes a bit blurry and I am able to control still only 1366x768 area.

Comment: Can you try this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10600/10206